# Carousel right click button not working properly

Tags: javascript, carousel

i have a typical carousel when i click left button if marginLeft is 0 it doesn't slide but i don't know what limited value to set for the slider when i click right button.

i tried calculating the images width and the margin space between them to set the limit value for the right button so slider doesn't slide past it but that doesn't work if you see it on another device because it's width is higher.

codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bXBaYW?editors=1010

```js
// caoursel
const carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
const leftArrow = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-left-arrow');
const rightArrow = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-right-arrow');
const slides = carousel.querySelector('.slides');
const slideImgs = carousel.querySelectorAll('.slide img');

let marginLeft = 0;

// works fine
function scrollLeft() {
  if (getComputedStyle(slides).marginLeft >= '0px') return;
  marginLeft += 310;
  slides.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + "px";
}

// need to set right slide a limited value.
function scrollRight() {
  if (getComputedStyle(slides).marginLeft <= '-1240px') return; //  dont scroll past this value
  marginLeft -= 310;
  slides.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + "px";
}

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', scrollLeft);
rightArrow.addEventListener('click', scrollRight);
```

i want the slider to stop sliding when i reach the last image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to not hardcode the width of the `.slides` container in CSS and JS.
Thus allowing you to dynamically compute the width of the `.slides` container, and the remaining space you can scroll/slide.

Below is an illustration of the variable and their values in relation to the whole component.

`remainingSpaceToScroll` will tell you how much space you have on the right, so you can not exceed the limit. The value of it can be found with simple math, by subtracting the sum of `parentWidth` and `currentScroll` from the value in `scrollWidth`.

[image]

Here is the code from your example updated so you can inspect.
I've removed the space between the slides for the simplicity sake.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BXpaNv

```
const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
const leftArrow = carousel.querySelector(".carousel-left-arrow");
const rightArrow = carousel.querySelector(".carousel-right-arrow");
const slides = carousel.querySelector(".slides");
const slideImgs = carousel.querySelectorAll(".slide img");

let marginLeft = 0;
let carouselImageWidth = 300;

function scrollLeft() {
  let parentWidth = carousel.offsetWidth;
  let scrollWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(slides).width, 10);
  let currentScroll = Math.abs(
    parseInt(getComputedStyle(slides).marginLeft, 10)
  );
  let remainingSpaceToScroll = currentScroll;

  if (remainingSpaceToScroll <= 0) {
    return;
  } else if (remainingSpaceToScroll >= carouselImageWidth) {
    marginLeft = -(currentScroll - carouselImageWidth);
  } else {
    marginLeft = -(currentScroll - remainingSpaceToScroll);
  }

  slides.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + "px";
}

function scrollRight() {
  let parentWidth = carousel.offsetWidth;
  let scrollWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(slides).width, 10);
  let currentScroll = Math.abs(
    parseInt(getComputedStyle(slides).marginLeft, 10)
  );
  let remainingSpaceToScroll = scrollWidth - (parentWidth + currentScroll);

  if (remainingSpaceToScroll <= 0) {
    return;
  } else if (remainingSpaceToScroll >= carouselImageWidth) {
    marginLeft = -(currentScroll + carouselImageWidth);
  } else {
    marginLeft = -(currentScroll + remainingSpaceToScroll);
  }

  slides.style.marginLeft = marginLeft + "px";
}

leftArrow.addEventListener("click", scrollLeft);
rightArrow.addEventListener("click", scrollRight);
```

HTML below:

```html
<p>click right arrow till end</p>

<div id="carousel">
        <span class="carousel-left-arrow arrow">&lt;</span>
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
      <a href="#">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
            </a>
      </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="carousel-right-arrow arrow">&gt;</span>
    </div>
```

CSS below:

```
#carousel {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 122px;
}

#carousel .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#carousel .arrow img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#carousel .carousel-left-arrow {
  width: 25px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#carousel .carousel-right-arrow {
  right: 0;
  width: 25px;
}

#carousel .slides {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
#carousel .slide {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

#carousel .slide > a {
  display: block;
}
#carousel .slides img {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply could you please explain the math done in remainingSpaceToScroll variable ? especially why did u subtract the parentWidth

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer adding a simple illustration and a description of the math. Please let me know if you need more info.